# undefined method `match?' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: regex, ruby, algorithm

I am trying to return a list/array of values from a range of (100..1000) that match the following criteria:

1. 3 digit value
2. All the digits in each value are unique.

```
$global_range = Array (100..999)
$fun = []

def listOfFunPossibilities
    # FUN values should meet the criteria below:
    # 1. 3 digit value
    # 2. All are unique

    $global_range.each do |i|
       if (!(/([0-9]).*?\1/)).match?(i)
           $fun.push(i)
       end
    end
    return $fun
end

listOfFunPossibilities()
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: `(100..999).select{|num| num.digits.uniq.size == 3 }`

Comment: Yes this works too if you don't need Regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply negation `!` too early:

```
if (!(/([0-9]).*?\1/)).match?(i)
```

so you first negate a regex (that is true for some reason) and then you try to call `match` on `true` value

Use instead:

```
if !(/([0-9]).*?\1/.match?(i))
```

or even

```
if !/([0-9]).*?\1/.match?(i)
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, however, I get a new error ```no implicit conversion of Integer into String (TypeError)``` after I do that

Comment: Use `match?(i.to_s)`, because regex matching doesn't work on integers

Comment: Whoa. Why the heck is a `Regexp` falsy? That smells like a bug.

Comment: I was surprised as well. Try `puts 1 if /a/` and `puts 1 if !/a/`

Comment: I asked a question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58340585/2988 Depending on the answers, I will file a bug. Interestingly, I was able to reproduce the behavior in at least three different implementations: YARV, JRuby, and TruffleRuby. MRuby doesn't have `Regexp`s, so the question doesn't come up. I'm trying to get Rubinius to build.

Comment: That's really interesting. Note that `!Regexp.new('')` is false so the regex created using a constructor is truthy.