# Why is a Regexp object considered to be "falsy" in Ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby, boolean, jruby, yarv

Ruby has a universal idea of "*truthiness*" and "*falsiness*".

Ruby *does* have two specific classes for Boolean objects, [`TrueClass`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/TrueClass.html) and [`FalseClass`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/FalseClass.html), with singleton instances denoted by the special variables `true` and `false`, respectively.

However, *truthiness* and *falsiness* are not limited to instances of those two classes, the concept is *universal* and applies to every single object in Ruby. Every object is either *truthy* or *falsy*. The rules are very simple. In particular, *only two objects are falsy*:

- `nil`, the singleton instance of [`NilClass`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html) and
- `false`, the singleton instance of [`FalseClass`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/FalseClass.html)

*Every single other object* is *truthy*. This includes even objects that are considered *falsy* in other programming languages, such as

- the [`Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html) `0`,
- the [`Float`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html) `0.0`,
- the empty [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) `''`,
- the empty [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) `[]`,
- the empty [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) `{}`,

These rules are built into the language and are not user-definable. There is no `to_bool` implicit conversion or anything similar.

Here is a quote from the [*ISO Ruby Language Specification*](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html):

> ## 6.6 Boolean values
>
> An object is classified into either a ***trueish object*** or a ***falseish object***.
>
> Only **false** and **nil** are falseish objects. **false** is the only instance of the class `FalseClass` (see 15.2.6), to which a *false-expression* evaluates (see 11.5.4.8.3). **nil** is the only instance of the class `NilClass` (see 15.2.4), to which a *nil-expression evaluates* (see 11.5.4.8.2).
>
> Objects other than **false** and **nil** are classified into trueish objects. **true** is the only instance of the class `TrueClass` (see 15.2.5), to which a *true-expression* evaluates (see 11.5.4.8.3).

[The executable Ruby/Spec seems to agree](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/if_spec.rb#L134-L140):

> ```rb
> it "considers a non-nil and non-boolean object in expression result as true" do
>   if mock('x')
>     123
>   else
>     456
>   end.should == 123
> end
> ```

According to those two sources, I would assume that [`Regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html)s are also *truthy*, but according to my tests, they aren't:

```rb
if // then 'Regexps are truthy' else 'Regexps are falsy' end
#=> 'Regexps are falsy'
```

I tested this on [YARV 2.7.0-preview1](http://atdot.net/yarv/), [TruffleRuby 19.2.0.1](https://GitHub.Com/Oracle/TruffleRuby), and [JRuby 9.2.8.0](http://JRuby.Org/). All three implementations agree with each other and disagree with the ISO Ruby Language Specification and my interpretation of the Ruby/Spec.

More precisely, `Regexp` objects that are the result of evaluating `Regexp` *literals* are *falsy*, whereas `Regexp` objects that are the result of some other expression are *truthy*:

```rb
r = //
if r then 'Regexps are truthy' else 'Regexps are falsy' end
#=> 'Regexps are truthy'
```

Is this a bug, or desired behavior?

Comment: Interesting thing is that `Regex.new("a")` is truthy.

Comment: `!!//` is false but `!!/r/` is true. Strange indeed.

Comment: @max `!!/r/` produces `false` for me using (RVM) Ruby 2.4.1.

Comment: Sorry my bad @3limin4t0r. You are right. I must have done something really stupid like leaving out an exclaimation mark.

Comment: A hypothesis, I think that `//` in `if // then` is interpreted as a test (a shortcut for `if //=~nil then`) (that is always falsy whatever the pattern) and not as an Regexp instance.

Comment: I think `if //` will act upon `$_` as is the case for cli usage.. for example: `seq 10 15 | ruby -ne 'print if /[35]/'` is same as `seq 10 15 | ruby -ne 'print if $_ =~ /[35]/'`

Comment: `ruby -le 'print "foo" if //'` doesn't print anything, whereas `ruby -le '$_ = ""; print "foo" if //'` will print `foo`... so, I think it depends upon what is the default value of `$_`

Comment: As mentioned above, `!!/r/ #=> false`, but the prefixed `!`s are actually syntactic sugar for `BasicObject#!`, so written as `/r/.!.!`, `true` is returned regardless as to what `$_` is set to and as one would expect for Ruby.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn’t a bug. What is happening is Ruby is rewriting the code so that

```
if /foo/
  whatever
end
```

effectively becomes

```
if /foo/ =~ $_
  whatever
end
```

If you are running this code in a normal script (and not using the `-e` option) then you should see a warning:

```
warning: regex literal in condition
```

This is probably somewhat confusing most of the time, which is why the warning is given, but can be useful for one lines using the `-e` option. For example you can print all lines matching a given regexp from a file with

```
$ ruby -ne 'print if /foo/' filename
```

(The default argument for `print` is `$_` as well.)

Comment: See also `-n`, `-p`, `-a` and `-l` options, as well as the handful of Kernel methods that are only available when `-n` or `-p` are used (`chomp`, `chop`, `gsub` and `sub`).

Comment: There is also [a second part of the parser](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_7_0_preview1/parse.y#L10874-L10879) where that warning is emitted. I don’t know what’s going on there though.

Comment: I believe that "second part" is the one that actually applies to this question. `NODE_LIT` with type `T_REGEXP`. The one you posted in your answer is for a *dynamic `Regexp` literal*, i.e. a `Regexp` literal which uses interpolation, e.g. `/#{''}/`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think you’re right. Poking around in the compiler and the generated bytecode, it looks like in the case of the dynamic regexp the parse tree is rewritten to explicitly add `$_` as a node which the compiler handles as normal, whilst in the static case it is all dealt with by the compiler. Which is a shame for me because “hey, you can see where the parse tree is rewritten here” makes for a nice answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is the result of (as far as I can tell) an undocumented feature of the ruby language, which is best explained by [this spec](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c866663784ea5a8f16e7fe5127127fb46ae90e6e/spec/ruby/language/regexp_spec.rb#L5-L15):

```
it "matches against $_ (last input) in a conditional if no explicit matchee provided" do
  -> {
    eval <<-EOR
    $_ = nil
    (true if /foo/).should_not == true
    $_ = "foo"
    (true if /foo/).should == true
    EOR
  }.should complain(/regex literal in condition/)
end
```

You can generally think of `$_` as the "last string read by `gets`"

To make matters even more confusing, [`$_` (along with `$-`) is **not** a global variable; it has local scope](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/globalvars.html).

---

When a ruby script starts, `$_ == nil`.

So, the code:

```
// ? 'Regexps are truthy' : 'Regexps are falsey'
```

Is being interpreted like:

```
(// =~ nil) ? 'Regexps are truthy' : 'Regexps are falsey'
```

...Which returns falsey.

On the other hand, for a **non-literal** regexp (e.g. `r = //` or `Regexp.new('')`), this special interpretation does not apply.

`//` is truthy; just like all other object in ruby besides `nil` and `false`.

---

Unless running a ruby script directly on the command line (i.e. with the `-e` flag), the ruby parser will display a warning against such usage:

> warning: regex literal in condition

You *could* make use of this behaviour in a script, with something like:

```
puts "Do you want to play again?"
gets
# (user enters e.g. 'Yes' or 'No')
/y/i ? play_again : back_to_menu
```

...But it would be more normal to assign a local variable to the result of `gets` and perform the regex check against this value explicitly.

I'm not aware of any use case for performing this check with an *empty* regex, especially when defined as a literal value. The result you've highlighted would indeed catch most ruby developers off-guard.

Comment: I only used the conditional as an example. `!// #=> true` has the same behavior and is not in a conditional. I couldn't find any boolean context (conditional or not), where it behaves as expected.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Do you mean e.g. `!// ? true : false` returns `true`? I think this is the same point again -- it's being interpreted like: `!(// =~ nil) ? true : false`

Comment: If you manually set `$_ = 'hello world'` before running the above code, then you should get a different result -- because `// =~ 'hello world'`, but does not match `nil`.

Comment: No, I mean `!//` *without the conditional* evaluates to `true`. The spec you cited is about a `Regexp` literal in a conditional, but in this example, there is no conditional, so this spec doesn't apply.

Comment: @JörgWMittag note that `//.!` evals to false, so the regex itself is indeed true

Comment: Ah.. Yeah, very surprising. The behaviour seems to be linked, though: `puts !//; $_ = ''; puts !//` -- I suppose because the parser expands it like a macro; it doesn't necessarily need to be inside a conditional?

Comment: (I'm going to show this to everybody who claims Ruby is easy or simple. I really like Ruby, but simple, it definitely ain't.)